# Can the jQuery UI datepicker show entire year and style selected date programmatically?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need a datepicker that will display the entire year for adding dates to a schedule, and I want to be able to make different dates different colors based on other criteria.  I know I can use the `beforeShowDay` function on page load, but what about changing the selected date's style programmatically?

Currently we have an asp.net button for each day that we change accordingly on postback but such an approach is clumsy at best and requires manually setting up the calendar.  Any suggestions?  I know I can display the calendar inline by attaching it to a span but not sure how to handle the other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiMonth.html)?

> The following example displays how you
>   can create a "multi month" date picker
>   which shows two consecutive months and
>   allows you to pick one date with them.

And [this](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/renderCalendarCallback.html)?

> The following example demonstrates the
>   use of $().renderCalendar as
>   introduced by jquery.datePicker.js -
>   we supply a renderCallback parameter
>   so that we have control over how each
>   day is rendered.